# jQuery History Access Denied

Tags: jquery, browser-state

i'm testing jquery history plugin (http://plugins.jquery.com/project/history) firefox fine working. but i'm testing ie7 browser has error reporting to "Access Denied". What solution this problem ?

Error Line : 
`var iframe = ihistory.contentWindow.document;`

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is trying to get the contents of an iframe. IE has lots of issues with that.
But if You get the Access Denied it looks like the iframe is in a different domain or it's not loaded yet.

The code should call this line in an onload event for this iframe. To make iframe lod faster you can set its src to an empty javascript call or something like that

Still using BBQ plugin seems a nice solution. I do that ;)

Comment: Or balupton's jQuery History plugin which has superb support, never had this error using it. http://www.balupton.com/projects/jquery-history

Answer (score 0):

Go check out the [BBQ plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/)

I found it much easier to use.